# Inserting html file inside content control range adds extra space at end in content control

Tags: c#, vsto

I have a use case where i am getting the content control text change from a word document. I am sending the content control text as html(to keep the formatting). In content control exit event i do

```
contentcontrol.Range.FormattedText.Copy(); or contentcontrol.Range.Copy()
```

and then get html from clipboard

```
string HTMLCode = Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Html).ToString();
```

The extra spaces are being inserted when i put this html in temp file and then insert it in the content control range:

```
contentControl.Range.Text = "";
contentControl.Range.FormattedText.InsertFile(tempFilename); or contentControl.Range.InsertFile(tempFilename);
```

One other thing i noticed is that after repeating this insert html task multiple times the extra space is added for only first few repetitions and then the it does not adds more space in the content control.

How can i stop this extra space added at the end of content control(the extra space is inside content control).

Comment: So HTMLCode has no extra space?

Comment: No, html does contains <span lang=\"EN-IN\"><o:p></o:p></span> and <w:sdtPr></w:sdtPr> tag that i tried removing but doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

On further analysis. i found that after inserting html file it adds `\r` at end of the range and deleting it using below code works:

```
Word.Range rng = doc.Range(contentControl.Range.End - 1, contentControl.Range.End);
rng.Delete();
```

I have asked the same on msdn form.
[link of question asked on msdn forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5b90e26c-ea23-499b-8b4f-78d555ce1e49/inserting-html-file-inside-content-control-range-adds-extra-space-at-end-in-content-control?forum=vsto)